# FormControl from Material UI React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

hi
What's special about FormControl from Material UI? Does it mean that child element is controlled?

```
<FormControl>
  <InputLabel htmlFor="my-input">Email address</InputLabel>
  <Input id="my-input" aria-describedby="my-helper-text" />
</FormControl>
```

Comment: If you tell us what part of the documentation you don't understand and why, you might get an answer. Otherwise, please read the documentation.

Comment: Try to find strength to explain how u understand it?

Comment: I can use NO formcontroll like this 
<InputLabel htmlFor="my-input">Email address</InputLabel>
 <Input id="my-input" aria-describedby="my-helper-text" />
why I should use FormControl? What for?

Otherwise, you might not answer this question at all

Answer (score 2):

According to the material-ui documentation:

> Provides context such as filled/focused/error/required for form
> inputs.

You basically use the FormControl component for accessibility reasons when you're building your own Field component([doc reference](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#accessibility)). It allows you to pass props such as `error` and change your UI.

For example the TextField Component is built on top of the FormControl too ([doc reference](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#advanced-configuration)).

N.B. Form fields are controlled when you manually handle (update on changes) their values

You can learn more by checking the [Material UI doc](https://material-ui.com/api/form-control/#formcontrol-api)

I also live you a CodeSandBox Example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-project-forked-uz3qt?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Can you show feature using examples? Provide context

Comment: Try reading the answer now, I updated it! Here you can find some live code examples https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-project-forked-uz3qt?file=/src/App.js
Let me know!

Comment: I guess I got it. So it means if I use FormControl I can pass some props like error and it's gonna make styles for all children we need  show error. I don't have to make styles for every child it's enough to pass some prop to FormControl, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you use FormControl you can pass some props like *error* and it's gonna make styles for all children we need to show error. You don't have to make styles for every child it's enough to pass some prop to FormControl.
Thnx to Francesco Cipolla for examples